# Loopback 4: Failed @repository dependency injection (TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined)

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs

I'm setting up Bearer Token authentication on my Loopback 4 app, and I'm following this general implementation: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/packages/authentication.

In my `src/providers/auth-strategy.provider.ts`, I need a reference to a repository object in order to query my data source. I hoped to achieve this with dependency injection using the `@repository` decorator in the constructor of the class I'm working in.

However, when I call `findOne()` on my repository reference created by the `@repository` decorator, the following error is produced:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`

Here's my version of `auth-strategy.provider.ts`:

```
import {Provider, inject, ValueOrPromise} from '@loopback/context';
import {Strategy} from 'passport';
import {
  AuthenticationBindings,
  AuthenticationMetadata,
} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {IVerifyOptions} from 'passport-http-bearer';
import {ApiClient} from '../models';
import {ApiClientRepository} from '../repositories';
import {Strategy as BearerStrategy} from 'passport-http-bearer';
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';

export class BearerStrategyProvider implements Provider<Strategy | undefined> {
  constructor(
    @inject(AuthenticationBindings.METADATA)
    private metadata: AuthenticationMetadata,
    @repository(ApiClientRepository)
    private apiClientRepository: ApiClientRepository,
  ) {}

  value(): ValueOrPromise<Strategy | undefined> {
    // The function was not decorated, so we shouldn't attempt authentication
    if (!this.metadata) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const name = this.metadata.strategy;
    if (name === 'BearerStrategy') {
      return new BearerStrategy(this.verify);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(`The strategy ${name} is not available.`);
    }
  }

  async verify(
    token: string,
    done: (error: any, user?: any, options?: IVerifyOptions | string) => void,
  ) {
    // call cb(null, false) when user not found
    // call cb(null, user) when user is authenticated
    let apiClient: ApiClient | null;
    try {
      apiClient = await this.apiClientRepository.findOne({
        where: {Token: token},
      });
      if (apiClient) {
        console.log("Found CLIENT!!! Here: " + apiClient.Email);
        done(null, {user: apiClient});
      } else {
        // if token not found in DB:
        done('Authentication Error.', false);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you bind the repository to the application context? https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Repositories.html#configure-controller

Comment: @rorschach The repository is definitely bound to the application context. I get a different error if I try to provide a key (string) to the `@repository` decorator which wasn't bound to the app context: `500 Error: The key repositories.ApiClientRepository2 was not bound to any value.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think in your case, the problem is the same as this one:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1835

You should bind the context of your verify function to your class, else `this` is not `BearerStrategyProvider` but `BearerStrategy`, then `this.apiClientRepository` does not exist in that class. You can bind it like this:

```
return new BearerStrategy(this.verify.bind(this));
```

Comment: Works! Thanks! Also for the great explanation. Seems obvious now. I could've swore I searched the Github Issues... Maybe it was the v3 Github Issues page.